# How to render in a Sitecore sublayout the content of some field in a parameter template and make it page editable?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a sublayout that I want to be able to use on multiple pages. I need to show a title bar at the top of the sublayout and I created a parameters template that contains a Title field. I want to display this Title in an `sc:Text` or `sc:FieldRenderer` control, to be able to page edit this value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the ascx you can have `<%= Title %>`

In the codebehind you can then declare it like this:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

And in Page_Load:

```
string rawParameters = Attributes["sc_parameters"];
NameValueCollection parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);
Title = parameters["Title"];
```

Assuming of course you're doing the code on an ascx file.

Although obviously this doesn't let you edit it in page editor.

[This](http://vapok.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/sitecore-6-using-parameters-in-web.html) is a good article to read on this

**[edit]**
Figured I'd add the code I'm using myself:

I have a helperclass which does:

```
public ParamHelper(System.Web.UI.UserControl control)
{
    _sublayout = control.Parent as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout;

    if (_sublayout != null)
    {
        _params = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(_sublayout.Parameters);
    }
}
```

and I can then get my Params:

```
public string GetParam( string key )
{
    string result = _params[key.Trim().ToLower()];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        result = string.Empty;
    }

    return (System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(result));
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if it is this way to be honest. 

If you are working in a Sitecore Sublayout you can just use ParseUrlParameters(this.Parameters), then it will be. If you're working in a UserControl you'll have to convert it to a Sublayout first.
For the code I use, please see the edit

Comment: I have the ascx file associated with the Sitecore sublayout where I am trying to use an <sc:Text> tag and link it to the Title field of the parameters template that is used by the sublayout. So far I tried any possible syntax that I can think of, and I get nowhere...

Comment: I already had all the code you added in the edit... if I put a literal on the page, I get the values on the page, that's no problem... my real issue is to make it page editable.

Comment: You're right. It isn't editable inline, but you can edit it by clicking on it, clicking More and selecting 'Edit the Component Properties'.

Comment: If I wrap my sublayout with an <sc:EditFrame> I can click on "edit the related item", but this brings up the Page where the sublayout is sitting, and the content editor would need to be savvy enough to know to click on Presentation / Details / etc. etc. It seems like there should be a better solution, a way to link directly an sc:text to that field, don't you think?

Comment: I agree that would be handy (and frankly I'd be surprised if there isn't a way), but currently our content editors work with clicking the title -> More -> Edit component properties.

Comment: you say "edit component properties", but I see "edit the related item"... how did you get it to show THAT message? Are you using an sc:EditFrame around the field?

Comment: Click the blue arrow pointing top-left until you have the complete usercontrol selected. Then More will give you Edit Component Properties as well

Comment: Gotcha... that answers my question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why does it need to be as a sublayout parameter and why not just a normal field in a template? You can use template inheritance to only add the field to only those templates that the sublayout will be used on or if it's going to be used a lot (or across random pages on the site) then add it to a base template. You can hide the field in the content editor if the sublayout is not used on the item by adding a dependency:

[Dynamic content editor templates using Rendering Dependencies](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/12/dynamic-content-editor-templates-using-rendering-dependencies)

You can then use `sc:text` or `sc:fieldrenderer` as per normal.

Comment: Say that I have a few templates per page type (home, product, one-column, two-column, etc.)... how am I supposed to know on which pages, in which sublayout the editor will add this "widget" (my sublayout)? What if he adds more than one instance of my sublayout on the same page in two different placeholders?

Comment: Adding to multiple templates would not be an issue, like I said just add it to a base template. But fair point about multiple instances, I thought this was a "bigger" module.

Comment: What about the other information that is displayed in the widget? If you have multiple instances of this where is the content defined? Are you setting this via `Datasource`? Why not just put the `Title` in the same template as this?